# Is there a way of communicating a specific sparse checkout between developers?

Tags: svn

I am investigating a means of reliably checking out a subset of a repository using several different sparse checkouts for deployment to developers, such that each gets their own 'view' of the file structure. While I can easily create the checkouts, I don't know how to communicate the checkout definition to developers. Is there any feature in SVN that might come close to this functionality?

Comment: How do you "easily* create those checkouts?

Comment: Using the sparse checkout feature of SVN/Tortoise. Create a checkout that represents the set of files I'd like to exist for a given developer. The next trick is deploying that checkout pattern to developers.

Comment: How do you know how to configure the sparse checkout dialog?

Comment: The help system is fairly comprehensive on the topic. Are you suggesting something?

Comment: I want to know where the information is stored. Is it in your head? Are there rules? How do you know what to select for a sparse checkout for developer X?

Comment: Ah I see, essentially several files in the repository have sensitive IP in them that we would like to protect. Ultimately as the core group we implicitly know which files need what protections, there are no general rules.

Comment: " sensitive IP in them that we would like to protect. " Sparse checkouts are not how you achieve this. You need to segregate your "sensitive" files into their own directory, then restrict access to that directory using Subversion's path-based authorization.

Comment: The intent ultimately is to be able to persistently define and create a file set that can be deployed to the external developer. They will not have access to the repository directly.

Answer (score 0):

Find a scripting language that is available on every developer's PC (bash, ANT, Python), write a script that does what you want (including asking for parameters when that's necessary) and commit the script.

Scripts are a great way to archive knowledge of build steps in a project.

**[EDIT]** I don't see how you could protect sensitive files in this way. Even if the original sparse checkout doesn't contain them, I can always tell Subversion later to do a full checkout. If sensitive files are an issue, I suggest to use several repositories to protect them.

If you just want to save disk space, you can use custom properties. But even then, you might have to checkout everything (not sure whether Subversion can tell you the property of a file that you didn't checkout) and then run a script to clean the workspace.

If merging wasn't such a mess in Subversion, I'd suggest to look at branches.

If you were using a distributes VCS like Git or Mercurial, I'd suggest to look into building your own checkout tool or use hooks to disallow access to certain files for certain users.

But subversion is probably not your best tool for this task.

Comment: While that would indeed work, maintaining it as the project file structure changes could become a bit of a headache. I am hoping for tools native to subversion and preferably the tortoise shell enhancement to easily nominate new files. Ideally files could be selectively tagged with the developers that can see/access them.

Comment: A script language could call subversion to analyze [subversion properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.properties.html).

Comment: Now that is getting devilishly close to what I'd like. Could such a script be seamlessly integrated into the shell extension or deployed to the server? As for defining the parameter of which filter, I was imagining the accessing user name as being the defining parameter for checkout content. Some developers will only interact with the repository through our core group and files provided in a yet undefined way. I am thinking about svnadmin dump and load for that section, not sure if that is the right way to go.